# Put object inside array in JOLT

Tags: json, mapping, transformation, jolt

I have an object which I want to put in an array in JOLT.

I tried putting [0] ahead of integratioEntity but it didn't work. I tried like- "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[0].integrationEntityHeader.action". Any idea on how to get the array outside the object.

**Updated Issue**- **Left side desired output and right side current output. The stuff highlighted in yellow is I don't want.**

[image]

JSON Input-

```
{
  "PURCHASE_ORDER_DISPATCH": {
    "MsgData": {
      "Transaction": {
        "PO_POD_HDR_EVW1": {
          "WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": 1,
          "WG_PO_CNTCT_EMAIL": "PeggyMeincke@westfieldgrp.com",
          "WG_REQUESTOR_EMAIL": "ZacharyEngels@westfieldgrp.com",
          "WG_REQ_FIRST_NAME": "Zachary",
          "WG_REQ_LAST_NAME": "Engels",
          "WG_DELIVER_TO": "ZacharyEngels@westfieldgrp.com",
          "BUSINESS_UNIT": "OFIC",
          "PO_ID": 25052,
          "VENDOR_SETID": "WCOS",
          "VENDOR_ID": 35958,
          "VNDR_LOC": 1,
          "PO_DT": "2020-01-24",
          "DB_NUMBER_BU": "",
          "DESCR_BU": "OhioFarmersInsuranceCo",
          "ADDRESS1_BU": "WESTFIELDCOMPANIES",
          "ADDRESS2_BU": "HOMEOFFICE",
          "ADDRESS3_BU": "1PARKCIRCLE",
          "ADDRESS4_BU": "",
          "CITY_BU": "WESTFIELDCENTER",
          "STATE_BU": "OH",
          "POSTAL_BU": "44251-5001",
          "COUNTRY_BU": "USA",
          "ADDRESS1_BILL": "",
          "ADDRESS2_BILL": "",
          "ADDRESS3_BILL": "",
          "ADDRESS4_BILL": "",
          "CITY_BILL": "",
          "STATE_BILL": "",
          "POSTAL_BILL": "",
          "COUNTRY_BILL": "",
          "CURRENCY_CD": "USD",
          "TAX_EXEMPT_ID": "",
          "STD_ID_NUM_VNDR": "",
          "NAME1_VNDR": "AMAZONCAPITALSERVICESINC",
          "ADDRESS1_VNDR": "410TERRYAVEN",
          "ADDRESS2_VNDR": "",
          "ADDRESS3_VNDR": "",
          "ADDRESS4_VNDR": "",
          "CITY_VNDR": "SEATTLE",
          "STATE_VNDR": "WA",
          "POSTAL_VNDR": 98109,
          "COUNTRY_VNDR": "USA",
          "PYMNT_TERMS_CD": "NET30",
          "DESCR50_PAY": "Net30",
          "BUYER_ID": 1083,
          "PO_AMT_TTL": 14.99,
          "TEXT254_CC1": "",
          "TEXT254_CC2": "",
          "VNDR_UPN_FLG": "N",
          "STD_ID_NUM_VNDRGLN": "",
          "STD_ID_NUM_BILLTO": "",
          "ATTN_TO": "ZacharyEngels",
          "PO_POD_LN_EVW1": {
            "WG_REQ_ID": 25694,
            "WG_CATEGORY_CD": "FSSUP",
            "WG_ITEM_TYPE": 0,
            "WG_ACCOUNT": 641100,
            "WG_DEPT_ID": 30400,
            "WG_PRODUCT": "",
            "BUSINESS_UNIT": "OFIC",
            "PO_ID": 25052,
            "WG_ASSET_GROUP": "",
            "WG_CAPITALIZE": "NO",
            "WG_PROFILE_ID": "",
            "WG_SPLIT_TYPE": 1,
            "WG_ASSET_LOC": "HOME",
            "WG_PROJECT": "",
            "VENDOR_SETID": "WCOS",
            "VENDOR_ID": 35958,
            "VNDR_LOC": 1,
            "LINE_NBR": 1,
            "INV_ITEM_ID": "",
            "DESCR254_MIXED": "147-1518156-3620845,1GreenMountainCoffeeRoastersCaramelVanillaCreamKeurigSingle-ServeK-CupPods,LightRoastCoffee,32Count",
            "UNIT_OF_MEASURE": "EA",
            "ITM_ID_VNDR": "B0798CX2Q9",
            "INV_ITEM_WEIGHT": 0,
            "INV_ITEM_HEIGHT": 0,
            "INV_ITEM_VOLUME": 0,
            "INV_ITEM_LENGTH": 0,
            "INV_ITEM_WIDTH": 0,
            "VNDR_CATALOG_ID": "",
            "MFG_ID": "",
            "MFG_ITM_ID": 5000196305,
            "CNTRCT_ID": "",
            "VERSION_NBR": 0,
            "CNTRCT_LINE_NBR": 0,
            "CAT_LINE_NBR": 0,
            "RELEASE_NBR": 0,
            "CANCEL_STATUS": "A",
            "UPN_ID": "",
            "PO_POD_SHP_EVW1": {
              "WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": 2,
              "WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": 2,
              "BUSINESS_UNIT": "OFIC",
              "PO_ID": 25052,
              "VENDOR_SETID": "WCOS",
              "VENDOR_ID": 35958,
              "VNDR_LOC": 1,
              "LINE_NBR": 1,
              "SCHED_NBR": 1,
              "DUE_DT": "2020-01-29",
              "SHIPTO_ID": "OFIC",
              "DESCR_SHIPTO": "OHIOFARMERSINSURANCECOMPANY",
              "ADDRESS1_SHIPTO": "OHIOFARMERSINSURANCECOMPANY",
              "ADDRESS2_SHIPTO": "1PARKCIRCLE",
              "ADDRESS3_SHIPTO": "POBOX5001",
              "ADDRESS4_SHIPTO": "",
              "CITY_SHIPTO": "WESTFIELDCENTER",
              "STATE_SHIPTO": "OH",
              "POSTAL_SHIPTO": "44251-5001",
              "COUNTRY_SHIPTO": "USA",
              "PRICE_PO": 14.99,
              "FREIGHT_TERMS": "FOBDEST",
              "QTY_PO": 1,
              "SHIP_TYPE_ID": "BEST_WAY",
              "CANCEL_STATUS": "A",
              "ATTN_TO": "",
              "STD_ID_NUM_SHIPTO": ""
            },
            "PSCAMA": {
              "AUDIT_ACTN": "A"
            }
          },
          "PSCAMA": {
            "AUDIT_ACTN": "A"
          }
        },
        "PSCAMA": {
          "LANGUAGE_CD": "ENG",
          "AUDIT_ACTN": "A",
          "BASE_LANGUAGE_CD": "ENG",
          "MSG_SEQ_FLG": "",
          "PROCESS_INSTANCE": 1199010,
          "PUBLISH_RULE_ID": "WG_MAIN_RULE",
          "MSGNODENAME": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

JOLT Spec-

```
[
  {
      "operation": "shift",
      "spec": {
          "#UPSERT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.action",
          "#integrationTrackingNumber": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.integrationTrackingNumber",
          "#referenceCodeForEntity": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.referenceCodeForEntity",
          "*": {
              "*": {
                  "*": {
                      "*": {
                          "PO_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.externalId",
                          "#APPROVED": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.status",
                          "PO_AMT_TTL": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.grossTotalAmount",
                          "FREIGHT_TERMS": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliveryTermCode",
                          "WG_REQUESTOR_EMAIL": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userEmailId",
                          "WG_DELIVER_TO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliverTo.userEmailId",
                          "#OFIC": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.company.companyCode",
                          "BUSINESS_UNIT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.businessUnit.buCode",
                          "PYMNT_TERMS_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.paymentTermId",
                          "#1": [
                              "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.costingSplitLevel",
                              "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.costingSplitType"
                          ],
                          "WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierAddress.addressERPID",
                          "CURRENCY_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierCurrencyCode",
                          "@WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierAddressERPID",
                          "VENDOR_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierERPID",
                          "WG_PO_CNTCT_EMAIL": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.suppPOContactEmail",
                          "#2": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierPOContactType",
                          "WG_REQ_FIRST_NAME": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userFirstName",
                          "WG_REQ_LAST_NAME": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userLastName",
                          "@CURRENCY_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.currency",
                          "@WG_DELIVER_TO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliverToUser.userEmailId",
                          "*": {
                              "WG_REQ_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.poDescription",
                              "#STANDARD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.poType",
                              "LINE_NBR": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.lineNumber",
                              "WG_CATEGORY_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.categoryCode",
                              "WG_ITEM_TYPE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.itemType",
                              "MFG_ITM_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.manufacturerPartID",
                              "ITM_ID_VNDR": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.supplierPartID",
                              "WG_ACCOUNT": {
                                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].value",
                                  "#name4": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].id",
                                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].type",
                                  "#GL_ACCOUNT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].name"
                              },
                              "WG_DEPT_ID": {
                                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].value",
                                  "#name3": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].id",
                                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].type",
                                  "#Westfield Department": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].name"
                              },
                              "WG_PRODUCT": {
                                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].value",
                                  "#name6": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].id",
                                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].type",
                                  "#Product/Parcel": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].name"
                              },
                              "WG_PROJECT": {
                                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].value",
                                  "#name5": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].id",
                                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].type",
                                  "#Project Code": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].name"
                              },
                              "WG_ASSET_GROUP": {
                                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].value",
                                  "#name10": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].id",
                                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].type",
                                  "#Asset Group": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].name"
                              },
                              "WG_CAPITALIZE": {
                                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].value",
                                  "#name9": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].id",
                                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].type",
                                  "#Capitalize": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].name"
                              },
                              "WG_PROFILE_ID": {
                                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].value",
                                  "#name9": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].id",
                                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].type",
                                  "#Profile Id": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].name"
                              },
                              "WG_ASSET_LOC": {
                                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].value",
                                  "#name2": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].id",
                                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].type",
                                  "#Business Unit": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].name"
                              },
                              "BUSINESS_UNIT": {
                                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].value",
                                  "#name7": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].id",
                                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].type",
                                  "#GL_ACCOUNT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].name"
                              },
                              "*": {
                                  "@WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddressType",
                                  "WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": {
                                      "2": {
                                          "@(2,DESCR_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressName",
                                          "@(2,ADDRESS1_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine1",
                                          "@(2,ADDRESS2_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine2",
                                          "@(2,ADDRESS3_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine3",
                                          "@(2,ADDRESS4_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine4",
                                          "@(2,CITY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.city",
                                          "@(2,POSTAL_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.zip",
                                          "@(2,STATE_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.state",
                                          "@(2,COUNTRY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.country"
                                      }
                                  },
                                  "WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressCode",
                                  "FREIGHT_TERMS": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliveryTermCode",
                                  "SHIPTO_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.locationCode.location.locationCode",
                                  "DUE_DT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliverOn",
                                  "@DUE_DT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliveryOn",
                                  "PRICE_PO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.marketPrice",
                                  "QTY_PO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.itemQuantity",
                                  "@WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddressCode",
                                  "@WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddressType",
                                  "#1": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.costingSplitType",
                                  "@WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": {
                                      "2": {
                                          "@(2,DESCR_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressName",
                                          "@(2,ADDRESS1_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine1",
                                          "@(2,ADDRESS2_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine2",
                                          "@(2,ADDRESS3_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine3",
                                          "@(2,ADDRESS4_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine4",
                                          "@(2,CITY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.city",
                                          "@(2,POSTAL_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.zip",
                                          "@(2,STATE_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.state",
                                          "@(2,COUNTRY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.country"
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  },
  {
      "operation": "shift",
      "spec": {
          "*": {
              "*": {
                  "integrationEntityHeader": "&2.&1.&",
                  "integrationEntityDetails": {
                      "*": {
                          "externalId": "&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                          "status": "&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                          "poHeader": {
                              "poDescription": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                              "poType": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                              "grossTotalAmount": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                              "deliveryTermCode": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                              "shipToAddressType": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                              "shipToAddress": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                              "company": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                              "businessUnit": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                              "locationCode": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                              "deliverOn": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                              "paymentTermId": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                              "costingSplitLevel": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                              "costingSplitType": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                              "supplierAddress": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                              "supplierAddressERPID": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                              "supplierCurrencyCode": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                              "supplierERPID": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                              "suppPOContactEmail": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                              "supplierPOContactType": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&"
                          },
                          "items": {
                              "item": {
                                  "lineNumber": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                  "requesterDetails": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                  "categoryCode": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                  "currency": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                  "deliverToUser": {
                                      "userEmailId": "&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&"
                                  },
                                  "deliverOn": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                  "itemType": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                  "manufacturerPartID": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                  "marketPrice": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                  "itemQuantity": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                  "shipToAddressCode": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                  "shipToAddressType": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                  "costingSplitType": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                  "supplierPartID": "&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                                  "validCombinations": {
                                      "itemDetails": {
                                          "validRules": {
                                              "field": {
                                                  "*": {
                                                      "id": "&11.&10.&9.&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.[&1].&",
                                                      "type": "&11.&10.&9.&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.[&1].&",
                                                      "name": "&11.&10.&9.&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.[&1].&",
                                                      "value": "&11.&10.&9.&8.&7.&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.[&1].&"
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  },
  {
      "operation": "cardinality",
      "spec": {
          "*": {
              "*": {
                  "*": {
                      "*": {
                          "status": "ONE",
                          "poHeader": {
                              "*": "ONE",
                              "company": {
                                  "*": "ONE"
                              }
                          },
                          "items": {
                              "item": {
                                  "costingSplitType": "ONE",
                                  "validCombinations": {
                                      "itemDetails": {
                                          "validRules": {
                                              "field": {
                                                  "id": "ONE",
                                                  "type": "ONE",
                                                  "name": "ONE",
                                                  "value": "ONE"
                                              }
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  },
  {
      "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
      "spec": {
          "*": {
              "*": {
                  "*": {
                      "*": {
                          "poHeader": {
                              "costingSplitLevel": "=toInteger",
                              "costingSplitType": "=toInteger",
                              "supplierPOContactType": "=toInteger"
                          },
                          "items": {
                              "item": {
                                  "costingSplitType": "=toInteger"
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  },
  {
      "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
      "spec": {
          "*": {
              "*": {
                  "*": {
                      "*": {
                          "*": {
                              "*": {
                                  "product": "=divide(1,@(1,itemQuantity))",
                                  "itemTotalAmount": "=divide(@(1,marketPrice),@(1,product))"
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
]
```

Curr Output

Comment: Please add your output.

Comment: Hey @MohammadReza, I did try to put the current output but stackoverflow is not allowing me to do that because it is exceeding the character limit however I have attached a screenshot of the output. If you want the full output you can use the spec and input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is adding this spec to end of your spec:

```json
,
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&1.&[]"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you please check the updated issue that I am getting.

Comment: @Sam Solved with new spec?

Comment: Yes got resolved. Thank You!